# continuity implies differentiability

Tags: derivatives, continuity

I am trying to prove that for f, a continuous function on the real numbers and differentiable on the real numbers except at c, if the limit of f'(x) as x tends to c exists then f is differentiable at c.

I thought the Mean Value Theorem might help but I don't know how to go about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $a \in (c-\varepsilon, c)$ such that $f'(a) = \frac{f(c) - f(c-\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon}$. Use the fact that $f'$ has a limit at $c$, you get that $f$ is differentiable on the left at $c$. Same thing on the right : $f$ is differentiable on the right at $c$. YOu can show easily it is the same value, so $f$ is differentiable on the left and on the right at $c$ with same value : it is then differentiable at $c$.

Comment: how would you show what the value is if you don't know the function?

Comment: You said that the limit exists. Consequently, if you note it $l$, you have $f'(x) \to l$ as $x \to c$. In my notations, as $\varepsilon \to 0$, $f'(a) \to l$.

Comment: yes, i meant for the left and right values sorry

Comment: The calculations show that the limits on the right and on the left do exist and are equal to $l$.

Answer (score 0):

By Lagrange's mean value Theorem, there is some $t_h \in (c, c+h)$ such that:
$$ \frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h} = f'(t_h) $$
Let $h \rightarrow 0 $ and use the squeeze theorem (which give us $t_h \rightarrow c$) to conclude.

Comment: Thank you! I am not familiar with the squeeze theorem is there other way to show that th tends to c?

Comment: Note that $ c \leq |t_h| \leq c+h $. Intuitively, you can see that when $h \rightarrow 0$ we have $t_h \rightarrow c$. This is squeeze theorem applied to this particular case: it proves rigorously that $t_h \rightarrow c$. I think it is the simplest way to show this.

Comment: But if th is in the open interval (c,c+h) then doesn't that mean that th cannot be equal to c or c+h?

Comment: An important aspect to notice when dealing with limits is that strict inequalities (that is, $<$, $>$) may become $\leq$, $\geq$. For example, $\frac{1}{x}>0$ for all $x>0$, but $$ 
\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0 \geq 0 $$ Returning to the above case, when we take the limit, the inequality $c < t_h < c + h$ becomes $c \leq t_h \leq c$, that is, $t_h=c$.